# How to search if a list contains values from another list TSQL

Tags: arrays, t-sql, compare, contains, exists

Ok I have done extensive research into this, and tried many techniques to no avail.

I have a list of Names, I have a list of Locations.  Some Locations have the full Names string contained within them.

I want to pull only the locations which contain the Names somewhere in them, and I do not want to check from a hard-coded list of %names%, needs to be scalable.
What i'm working with is below (I don't check for existing temp tables everytime, sry not really a need)

ALSO ALL QUERIES WORK INDIVIDUALLY, except the last one where i finally try to combine

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProviderList') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ProviderList

SELECT distinct
Station
,StaffName --first and last concatenated
,lastName
,ProviderID
--,[ProviderRole]
INTO #ProviderList
FROM --Omited--
Where PrimaryProviderSID in (Select distinct
                            PrimaryProviderSID
                        ----
                        Where PrimaryPosition not like '%zz%'
                            AND PrimaryProviderID > 0)
    AND [TerminationDate] is null
AND (InactivationDate is null)




Select LastName 
INTO #LastName
from #ProviderList


/* Failed experiment
Declare @Names as Table(Name varchar(max))
Insert Into @Names Select LastName 
from #ProviderList

--Select* From @Names

Failed experiment
*/






SELECT distinct [Many fields...],
  LocationName
Into #LocationName
  FROM ------
Where LocationName not like '%z%'
    AND ---filtering criteria to make my list
```

---------------The part where it comes together

I want to select Everyting from #LocationName but only the records which contain ANY record from the Names list, they will only contain one or none

```
Select *
From #LocationName  
Where #LastName in (LocationName)?
Where '%' + LastName + '%'  ? --tried concatenation, i want a fuzzy search
Where #LocationName contains(LocationName, #LastName)? ---i know syntax is wrong but this has not proven to be the correct technique anyway
Where Exists(Select LastName from #LastName) --made no change but Not Exists returned nothing...
```

----------Coworker just brought me this:

```
 select lastname
 from #LastName
 Where charindex(LastName,
 (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + LocationName
  FROM #LocationName
  FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Txt )

  )>1
```

------But that is only going to give us a list of names that are contained in the LocationName field, we also want to pull the Location Name

I know this is a long one, but i hope I was relatively clear about what needs to be done at least if not how I'm doing it.

I feel like I want to make an array and compare each Name value individually to see if it is contained in the LocationName, then if yes add it to a new list. That would be ideal

Comment: A sample set of the data might clarify what you are asking. 

I think your saying you have table Names (name) with values similar to 'bob' and 'jim' and table Location (locationName, etc) with locationName values similar to 'house of bob', 'jims office', 'joes crab shack'. And you want to select the rows containing 'house of bob' or 'jims office' since the have values containing one of the names.

Comment: ^that is exactly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
CREATE TABLE #NAMES (NAME VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #LOCATIONS (LOCATIONNAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #NAMES 
SELECT 'DAVE' UNION
SELECT 'BOB' UNION 
SELECT 'JIMMY'

INSERT INTO #LOCATIONS 
SELECT 'TODDS BOAT' UNION
SELECT 'MARYS HOUSE' UNION
SELECT 'DAVES HOTTUB' UNION
SELECT 'JIMMYS CRICKEY CLUB'

SELECT L.*
FROM #LOCATIONS L
CROSS APPLY #NAMES N
WHERE CHARINDEX(N.NAME, L.LOCATIONNAME)>0
```

Comment: That does answer what I think gruff was asking. It can also be done with a correlated subquery. The execution plan on this sample data is the same either way.

SELECT L.*
  FROM #LOCATIONS L
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #NAMES N WHERE CHARINDEX(N.NAME, L.LOCATIONNAME)>0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does deserve a separate answer rather than just a comment to JiggsJedi.

It can also be done with a correlated subquery. The execution plan on this sample data is the same either way.

Use the sample data from JiggsJedi.

```
SELECT L.* 
  FROM #LOCATIONS L 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM #NAMES N 
                WHERE CHARINDEX(N.NAME, L.LOCATIONNAME) > 0)
```